# How to name a good/meaningful type?

Tags: c, encapsulation, naming

Device_Manager.h

```
typedef enum
{
    DNM = 0x2A,

}TYPE_e;

typedef struct DEVICE_s* p_DEVICE;
typedef p_DEVICE(*FUNC)(char* name, TYPE_e type, uint32_t ip, uint16_t method, uint16_t groupRule);   

p_DEVICE DeviceManager_New(void);
p_DEVICE DeviceManager_Ctor(char* name, TYPE_e type, uint32_t ip, uint16_t method, uint16_t groupRule);
p_DEVICE DeviceManager_Dtor(p_DEVICE element);
```

Device_Manager.c

```
struct DEVICE_s
{
    uint32_t IP;
    TYPE_e Type;
    uint16_t Method;
    uint16_t GroupRule;
    char Name[40];
    FUNC fp_Ctor, fp_Dtor;    //this line needs modification
}DeviceSet[32],DeviceTemp;

p_DEVICE DeviceManager_InitObject(p_DEVICE* self)
{
    (*self) = DeviceManager_New();
    (*self)->IP = 0;
    (*self)->Type = 0;
    (*self)->Method = 0;
    (*self)->GroupRule = 0;
    memset((*self)->Name, 0, NAME_SIZE);
    (*self)->fp_Ctor = DeviceManager_Ctor;
    (*self)->fp_Dtor = DeviceManager_Dtor;    // warning: assign to wrong type
    return (*self);
}
p_DEVICE DeviceManager_New(void)
{
    return &DeviceTemp;
}
p_DEVICE DeviceManager_Ctor(char* name, TYPE_e type, uint32_t ip, uint16_t method, uint16_t groupRule)
{
    memcpy(DeviceTemp.Name, name, sizeof(name));
    DeviceTemp.Type = type;
    DeviceTemp.IP = ip;
    DeviceTemp.Method = method;
    DeviceTemp.GroupRule = groupRule;
    return &DeviceTemp;
}
p_DEVICE DeviceManager_Dtor(p_DEVICE element)
{
    element->IP = 0;
    element->Type = 0;
    element->Method = 0;
    element->GroupRule = 0;
    memset(element->Name, 0, NAME_SIZE);
    return element;
}
```

This is my first time implementing encapsulation concept and came across some problem.

In header file, I used typedef to define type "FUNC" as a function pointer.

I think this name "FUNC" is not clear enough, because this naming fashion will result in:

```
struct DEVICE_s
{
    uint32_t IP;
    TYPE_e Type;
    uint16_t Method;
    uint16_t GroupRule;
    char Name[40];
    FUNC1 fp_Ctor;    //not clear
    FUNC2 fp_Dtor;    //not clear
}DeviceSet[32],DeviceTemp;
```

fp_Ctor and fp_Dtor are both same type(function pointer) and differ in argument's number.

I always struggle in naming type. Can offer some suggestions on naming type?

Comment: *"both same type(function pointer) and differ in argument's number"* - If the number of arguments differs, they are not the same type, are they?

Comment: In book OOP by Axel Schreiner **"What exactly is a data type? We can take several points of view. A data type is a set of values. Alternatively, we can define a data type as a set of values plus operations to work with them."** I think I still cannot understand it.

Comment: And calling with a **specific number of arguments** is an operation, which is different from calling with **another number of arguments**.

Comment: @StoryTeller May you please give me more direction of this very sentence? I'm not good at this concept

Comment: I would suggest you put the book aside for now, and focus on learning C and OOP separately. Schreiner's books assumes (a lot of) familiarity with both. You'll only get more confused as you go along.

Comment: **If the number of arguments differs, they are not the same type, are they?** I'm not sure about that. Moreover, I'm not getting notion of data type.

Comment: @StoryTeller Okay...I'll listen to you. How do I do now?

Comment: Well, the [ACCU](https://accu.org/index.php/book_reviews_redirect) publishes reviews of books. They are reviewed by seasoned programmers, *for* other programmers. You can look for reviews (and books) by searching there according to topic.

Comment: @AndyLin Please drop that book already. It is needlessly complex and has lots of confused ideas. It is valuable to prove a point - yes you can do OO in C just fine - but beyond that, it is not good studying material for how to do OO in practice.

Comment: Also, this question isn't necessarily opinion-based. How to name opaque types and member functions when doing OO C isn't really subjective - you have to rely on prefix naming rather than `this` pointers, as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all a bit subjective, but I would start with dropping the style of hiding pointers behind typedef and smear some manner of "Hungarian notation" over it. A whole lot of C programmers will agree there.

So the first suggestion is to go with

```
typedef struct DEVICE_s DEVICE_s;
```

And then define your opaque interface based on `DEVICE_s*` instead. Not only is it easier to read, you filter out obfuscation like a caller attempting to pass `p_DEVICE*` to the user-defined functions etc, because they don't realize they already have a pointer. (Win32 API suffers heavily from this problem.)

Then your constructor becomes

```
DEVICE_s* DeviceManager_Ctor ( ...
```

And all member functions will take a `DEVICE_s*` parameter rather than a `p_DEVICE` by value. The caller will have to declare pointers instead of objects, making it clear to them that they have a pointer to incomplete type and nothing they can/should play around with.

Next up you can drop the pointer hiding in the function pointer too. This is less of an issue, but it is nice to be consistent:

```
typedef DEVICE_s* DeviceManager_Ctor_t ( ...
```

Your function pointer definitions would then become:

```
DeviceManager_Ctor_t* Ctor;
```

You can drop the "fp" naming as it is already obvious that the type is a function pointer.

---

As a side note, I would recommend to avoid mimicking C++ member functions with `obj.member` notation. Because in C, lacking a `this` pointer, you will end up with `obj.member(&obj, ...)` which is kind of redundant.

Rather just accept that C is the way it is and call member functions as `DeviceManager_Ctor(obj);` where `obj` is declared as `DEVICE_s* obj;`. The key to readable OO code is to use a consistent source code prefix for all functions belonging to the "class", as you already do: `DeviceManager_`.

Comment: Hi, thanks to you. I'm a bit confused regarding your comment about function pointer. How`DEVICE_s* DeviceManager_Ctor`become `typedef DEVICE_s DeviceManager_Ctor_t`?

Comment: @AndyLin Sorry there was a typo, it should be `typedef DEVICE_s* DeviceManager_Ctor_t`. Fixed. That is, you typedef a function type called `DeviceManager_Ctor_t`, returning a `DEVICE_s*`. Then `DeviceManager_Ctor_t*` is a function pointer of that function type. But as mentioned at the bottom of the answer, I would rather recommend to not have ctor/dtor as function pointers, but simply indicate that they are member functions by the use of a function naming prefix.

Answer (score -1):

[Linux kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html#typedefs) suggests to use typedefs with caution. "Methods" or function pointers are usually grouped into a operations struct. For example:

```
// DeviceManager.h
//

struct device_operations;

struct device {
    const char *name;
    const struct device_operations *ops;
};

struct device_operations {
    void (*ctor)(struct device *d, const char *name);
    void (*dtor)(struct device *d);
};

struct device *DeviceManager_new(const char *name);


// DeviceManager.c
//

#include <stdlib.h>

static void DeviceManager_ctor(struct device *d, const char *name);
static void DeviceManager_dtor(struct device *d);

static struct device_operations DeviceManager_ops = {
    .ctor = DeviceManager_ctor,
    .dtor = DeviceManager_dtor,
};

struct device *DeviceManager_new(const char *name)
{
  struct device *d = malloc(sizeof(*d));
  if (!d)
    return NULL;

  d->ops = &DeviceManager_ops;
  d->ops->ctor(d, name);

  return d;
}

static void DeviceManager_ctor(struct device *d, const char *name) { /* ... */ }
static void DeviceManager_dtor(struct device *d) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Implementing vtable is only really necessary for virtual methods. And whenever that happens it's time to think if C is really the right tool for the job or if the program design should be reconsidered. I heavily recommend the advice in Lundins answer that these function pointers should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: The Linux kernel coding style is mostly a subjective style document, without any rationales. As coding standards go, it is of garage hacker quality. Please don't use it as reference for how to write C programs. Just as the Linux kernel in itself should never be used as some canonical reference. If you want a serious coding standard written by professionals, use MISRA-C or CERT-C.

Comment: As for this specific code, you clutter the ctor/dtor of the specific object together with some generic allocation code. I don't see any reason to do that in the generic case, as it gives no benefits. Although on some embedded systems you'll want to manually use a memory pool instead of malloc. But that's implementation details for a specific system.